# How to take advantage of new DSP effects available from API 16+?

Tags: android, signal-processing

`android.media.audiofx.NoiseSuppressor`, `android.media.audiofx.AcousticEchoCanceler`, `android.media.audiofx.AutomaticGainControl` are only available since API level 16 and on specific devices. `effectname.isAvailable()`can check if such effect is implemented in device and is available.On my samsuung galaxy SII with stock android 4.1, `isAvailable()` returns true but when i try to `create()` the effect i get this error in my logcat for the above three methods:

```
04-26 22:29:11.430: E/AudioEffect(18365): set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -22
04-26 22:29:11.430: E/AudioEffects-JNI(18365): AudioEffect initCheck failed -4
04-26 22:29:11.435: E/AudioEffect-JAVA(18365): Error code -4 when initializing AudioEffect.
04-26 22:29:11.435: W/AcousticEchoCanceler(18365): not implemented on this devicenull
```

here is one of my enable methods:

```
    public void enableAutomaticGainControl(int audioSessionId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
            && android.media.audiofx.AutomaticGainControl.isAvailable()
            && agc == null && audioSessionId != 0) {
        agc = AutomaticGainControl.create(audioSessionId);
        if (agc != null) {
            agc.setEnabled(true);
            Log.i(TAG, "AutomaticGainControl enabled.");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "AutomaticGainControl can not be created.");
        }
    }
}
```

audio session id is correct since other effects(such as bass boost and equaliser) work fine.

Why an effect is available but can not be created?